# Google Colab throwing error on pip install

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

The whole code was working till yesterday but suddenly Google Colab is throwing an error on the first line of the cell block.

```
!pip install -U -q PyStemmer
```

This is the error message -

```
----> 1 get_ipython().system('pip install -U -q PyStemmer')
Error: Unknown request type: cell_update_stdin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by the Colab engineer on Github refreshing the page solves the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't as of 2024-02-01

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem, I just created a new notebook and copied the code and this seemed to resolve it. No idea what caused it.